# How to set Visual Studio 2013 as default git difftool and mergetool?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, github-for-windows, difftool

I've followed some tutorials and posts but still seems to not work. Is it even possible to set VS2013 as default merge/diff tool for git on Windows?

**Config**

```
[mergetool "vs13"]
    cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\vsDiffMerge.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" //t
[difftool "vs13"]
    cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\Common7\\IDE\\vsDiffMerge.exe" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$MERGED" //m
[diff]
    tool = vs13
[merge]
    tool = vs13
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\testvisualstudio [master +0 ~1 -0]> git mergetool
No files need merging

C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\testvisualstudio [master +0 ~1 -0]> git difftool
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: eval: line 122: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib: eval: line 122: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\I
DE\vsDiffMerge.exe $REMOTE $LOCAL $BASE $MERGED //m'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670148/using-visual-studio-2012s-built-in-merge-tool-with-git/18133855#18133855