# Azure Devops Repos with TFVC vs Git

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, tfvc

I've been trying to find out which option is best for Azure Devops, but I couldn't find a clear answer in old posts.

My current project has TFVC in Azure Repos, and we are thinking to use Pipelines and Releases modules soon. I noticed 2 things, first that TFVC doesn't support YAML to create Pipelines (Everything is done through UI) and second, there is no that much information out there of people using TFVC in comparison with Git.

I'm not sure if these are enough reasons to swap to Git, and I'd like to get some advice on moving to Git is the best choice.

Cheers

Comment: Your question is opinion based so will probably be closed because not allowed in Stackoverflow. But indeed, Git is much more flexible and so won the version control 'war'. Nowadays, most of the tools and features are built around git. So, yes, if you hesitate, I think it's a good move to migrate. Disclaimer: maintainer of git-tfs because I never wanted to use TFVC anymore as git is such a pleasure...

Comment: ... a pleasure (I **strongly** agree) after the initial shock. :-D (`git add`? again??? But isn't the file _added_ already?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What is not in here based on opinion? :D 50% of the posts? Joking. Anyway, it could be answered with main differences, advantages and disadvantages. That's the type of answer is very welcome. Thanks

Comment: Also, be aware that the answer should be based on Devops!

Comment: For advantages of one solution over the other one, use your preferred search engine. An example: https://www.red-gate.com/blog/why-to-use-git-instead-of-tfs-tfvc

Comment: Or that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107701/what-are-the-big-differences-between-tfvc-tfs-version-control-and-git-for-sour