# Running "git difftool" at Git Bash opens up multiple, empty instances of Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, git-bash, git-diff

When I run the following command in Git Bash:

```
git difftool mybranch master
```

git opens up several empty instances (no files open, no diff shown) of Visual Studio, one after another.

Here's the relevant portion of my global `.gitconfig`, located in my home directory:

```
[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe"' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" //t
    keepbackup = false
    trustexistcode = true
```

I got this snippet from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18133855/1063392), which describes how to use the built-in Visual Studio diff tool with git.

My theory is that `vsDiffMerge.exe` is being called with the wrong parameters.

I've already tried creating a wrapper `.sh` script for `vsDiffMerge.exe`:

```
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/vsDiffMerge.exe" "$2" "$5"
```

and setting it as an external tool in my `.gitconfig`, like this:

```
[diff]
    external = (path to my shell wrapper)
```

but this had a similar effect to my current efforts, except that it only opened a single instance of Visual Studio, and had to be run with `git diff` instead of `git difftool`.

Any help would be much appreciated - I haven't been able to find much relevant information on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact reason why my previous configuration wasn't working, but this is now working for me:

**In my `.gitconfig`:**

```
[diff]
    tool = vsDiffMerge

[difftool "vsDiffMerge"]
    cmd = "'"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/vsDiffMerge.exe"' $LOCAL $REMOTE"
    trustExitCode = true
```

I no longer need the shell wrapper script, and I can successfully view diffs like so:

```
git difftool mybranch master
```

Comment: I had the problem where running `git difftool <branch1>..<branch2>` (using VS2013) would open up each file diff in a new instance of VS. lol. Removing the `//t` switch/argument and removing `prompt = [false|true]` seems to have fixed that problem.